# User Content with image gallery and text

Tags: users, nodes, media

i am building a little "show and tell" page, for showing pictures of a room, basically as practice to get into Drupal but the page will be used later.

What i have managed (as it was pretty easy): 
1) Generate an custom content type for the room
2) Add fields for the room for the information

But now i got stuck: The users should have the ability to upload multiple pictures within the form (i think pluploads will handle this). The room should then have a gallery for the pictures. How do i add the upload form to the content type and how do i manage to get a gallery in the content type, that shows only the pictures a user added to this *post*

I tried the media gallery module, but it seems to only have static album pages and can not be embedded in a content type.

Answer (score 1):

You can configure the number of images the user can upload while creating a node in the field settings (manage fields page of your content type)

Once the images are uploaded you can display them in a slider/carrousel style using modules such as :

- [Galleria](http://drupal.org/project/galleria)
- [Gallery formatter](http://drupal.org/project/galleryformatter)

Or you can just display clickable thumbnails (and a bigger version in a lightbox.)

You can set the image dimensions in : /admin/config/media/image-styles

You need to tell me more about the way you want your images to be displayed.
What version of drupal are you using ?